# Conexão Java mySQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou com um problema ao seguir esta [video Aula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00KaJs1LMGw):

Pareço seguir o  que ele manda fazer mas a linha fica vermelha e com erros:

```
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/videoAulaJDBC", "root", "");
```

O erro que acontece são os seguintes:

> 1º unreported exception sqlException: Must be caughtor declared to be
>   thrown  ("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/videoAulaJDBC", "root", "");
>
> 2º unreported exception sqlException is never thrown in body of
>   correnponding try statement  } catch (SQLException ex){

```
             System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro de SQL");
```

**Código:**

```
package View;

import java.sql.Connection;     // Conexão 
import java.sql.DriverManager;  // Me conecte com o driver de comunicação
import java.sql.ResultSet;      // Repositório de registros vindos de uma consulta
import java.sql.SQLException;   // Tratamento de erros
import java.sql.Statement;      // Repositório para envio de registros

/**
 *
 * @author brainiac
 */
public class JCadClienteView extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /** Creates new form NovoJDialog */
    public JCadClienteView(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Cadastro de Cliente");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(80, 80, 80)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(47, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39))
        );

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Dados do Cliente"));

        jLabel3.setText("Endereço");

        jLabel2.setText("Nome");

        jLabel4.setText("CPF");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1))
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2))
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 311, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jButton1.setText("Limpar");

        jButton2.setText("Salvar");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)))
                .addContainerGap(44, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            //Botaõ Salvar
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possível encontrar a classe");
            // Criando variável de conexão
            Connection con;
            //Connection con;

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/videoAulaJDBC", "root", "");

        } catch (SQLException ex){

             System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro de SQL");
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JCadClienteView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JCadClienteView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JCadClienteView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JCadClienteView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JCadClienteView dialog = new JCadClienteView(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Adicione a pilha de erro na pergunta também. E o link do outro erro não está abrindo.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme,
O erro está dentro das linhas:
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/videoAulaJDBC", "root", "");

        } catch (SQLException ex){

mais precisamente em, onde ficam selecionadas:

Comment: Faltou você adicionar a pilha de erro na pergunta.

Comment: 1º
unreported exception sqlException: Must be caughtor declared to be thrown


2º
unreported exception sqlException is never thrown in body of correnponding try statement

Comment: Você pode adicionar na pergunta? Assim fica mais facil alguem te ajudar, com todas as informações na pergunta.

Comment: Claro, desculpe, sou novo por aqui

Answer (score 1):

Sua linha de conexão está dentro do catch, quando deveria estar dentro do try, por isso gera um erro de unreported exception, pois este método de conexão pode lançar uma exceção checada, que deve ser obrigatóriamente tratada com try/catch ou lançada com throws.

Altere o método para o seguinte:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   try {
        //Botaõ Salvar
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Criando variável de conexão
        Connection con;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/videoAulaJDBC", "root", "");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Não foi possível encontrar a classe");
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro de SQL");
    }
}
```